# Jump by touch Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I writing game on Unity C#

This is simple runner.

I have Platformer2DUserControl Script.

Here is it

```
 using UnityEngine;
using UnitySampleAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnitySampleAssets._2D

{

[RequireComponent(typeof (PlatformerCharacter2D))]
public class Platformer2DUserControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlatformerCharacter2D character;
    private bool jump ;

    private void Awake()
    {
        character = GetComponent<PlatformerCharacter2D>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            character.Move(1, false, jump);

        if (!jump)
        // Read the jump input in Update so button presses aren't missed.
        jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Read the inputs.
        bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl);
       // float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        // Pass all parameters to the character control script.
        character.Move(1, false, jump);
        jump = false;
    }
}
}
```

I try to make  that player jumps when i touch screen on my phone.

But it don't jump.

What wrong in my code?

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the the object to jump on touch use

```
Input.GetButton("Fire1")
```

It is predefined to left mouse click and also work for single touch input

Answer (score 0):

```
Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)
```

It is my understanding that SPACE works for touch as well.