# Update won't detect my jump input correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I'm following some guides and from what I've seen using the update function is a good thing for the jump action, but when I do it the update sends me to a different location.

##### Jump Related Function:

```cs
void Update(){
   if(dead == false){
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
         if(OnGround == true){
            r.velocity = new Vector2(r.velocity.x, jumpForce * time.deltaTime);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

From an internet search I found the following, but they didnt help me so much [option1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784637/jump-by-touch-unity-c-sharp) and [option2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62492270/unity3d-rigidbody-jump-input-repeats-constantly)

Mostly it moves me to a different location or jumps me too much high or too much low, never a good proper jump, I really have no idea what to do, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `Time.deltaTime` when you're assigning velocities directly. The value of `Time.deltaTime` depends on the frame rate, which is expected to jitter, which gets inherited into your jump so that you get a quasi random velocity and jump height.

```csharp
if(!dead && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && OnGround){
  r.velocity = new Vector2(r.velocity.x, jumpForce);
}
```

typically the `AddForce` function is used for jumps, which is technically the "correct" way to go about it, but I know plenty of people that prefer your method. In any case I'll just put it here for reference.

```csharp
if(!dead && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && OnGround){
  r.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While your code is correct, I suggest using `Rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3 force);` or in case you are using rigidbody 2d `Rigidbody2D.AddForce(Vector2 force);` instead of using `r.velocity=...`. To make it easier to debug - you can create a public variable for the force and tweak it while in play mode until you get satisfactory results.

Comment: why go through a force calculation requiring to take the mass etc into account when you already know that you want to set the velocity to a certain value?